# What is the function of the BJT and diode in this circuit?

Tags: dc-motor

[image]

I want to know why we need to use a BJT and diode in this circuit to activate the DC motor.

Comment: I do believe Q has its emitter and collector wired backwards. As it is it will do nothing. I assume the OC1A output is PWM.

Comment: Bit of a strange arrangement. In this case, the NPN is arranged to use its collector as an emitter and its emitter as a collector. The active \$\beta\$ is terrible, but in this case all that's needed is a saturated switch and arranging it this way can mean somewhat smaller \$V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$ (slightly better switch at the expense of more base drive current and a weird NPN arrangement that may confuse some.) \$D_2\$ is needed to allow the inductance of the motor to have a de-energizing path when turned off. \$D_1\$ may not be strictly needed, but is a cheap extra safety measure.

Comment: @Sparky256 No, it will work okay. It's just weird to use an NPN like that. It's a very old trick that goes back many decades in order to reduce \$V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$ a bit. Luckily, I'm old enough to remember an article or two on the topic.

Comment: @jonk. New one for me jonk. Early 1980's PWM control was with a 'backward' NPN to control toroid drive current which set the pulse width.

Comment: I know what you’re thinking @jonk but the V+ is reversed for that.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I'm not sure what you are referring to, because the NPN collector (in the existing schematic there) is at (-). Which is exactly where it should be. The NPN emitter is being used as a collector to pull down one side of the motor, the other side of which is at (+), also where it should be.

Comment: @Sparky256 If early 1980's PWM used a backward NPN for an application you were aware of, then it's not new to you.

Comment: Ok right but the backwards CE as I recall has only hFE =1 to 5 and that’s not enuf.to drive a motor at the expense of a lower Vce(sat) @1A

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist That assumes you know what's driving it. All I see is a wire going to something I've not yet researched. An I/O pin will typically have a series resistance in the area of about 100 Ohms, give or take, so I'd be expecting a fair bit of base current. Also, I've no idea about the motor inductance or resistance. So I can't address "not enuf" without more information. You seem to be able to do so, though. I'm impressed. Finally, I think the OP was wondering about a good question, regardless.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist The other fly in the ointment here is that your answer suggests a PNP?? That makes me wonder.

Comment: The NPN is a poor choice as the CMOS already goes to Vcc with a  50 ohm source (RdsOn) and inverting the output with a typical nifty unity gain NPN does nothing to boost the current.

Answer (score 1):

The transistor here is “supposed to” boost the logic current with current gain but as a low side switch. It may only be as low as 10% of hFE as a normal PNP switch and initially the idle motor draws up 10x input current to drive the low resistance (DCR spec) of the motor when Vce=Vce(sat).

Thus you must know Ohm’s Law , the DCR resistance of motor coil , and the Ron for CMOS 5V Logic.

Then you must compute voltage attenuation drop.  But this poor design cannot do this very well from a reversed NPN.

This is a low side inverting switch configuration to near 0V (if no load) with motor’s other side  to V+.  But a reverse NPN has almost no current gain (except a few types) i.e. x1

**However an NPN can  work backwards as a Low current 0mV switch but possibly fail with hot spots undetected from Vbe reverse =9V (>5max) driving say a 100mA motor with a 1A start Current.**

An PNP will work better but with Collector output.**.   The CE junction is designed for high reverse  voltage and much higher current gain used properly, with forward Vbe, while the BE junction in reverse must not avalanche unless you want a Zener with higher capacitance and partial damage from hot spots.

Let me say how a better design works.  Use an NFET or NPN switch which both have a transimpedance gain, gm.

When turned off, from on=low, to high, the motor inductance creates a large LdI/dt=V +ve spike in the opposite direction when  the collector was active ON, which must be clamped the reverse diode D2, to V+. As the motor slows down it now generates a voltage and is shorted by the current thru that diode to V+ till it stops!, with a voltage proportional to speed. If no diode, it might be a very large spike then coast to a stop.

Thus the diode D2, (clamps the overvoltage) and must handle the same BEMF  current as the transistor for some inertial time response as D2 acts as a dynamic brake.

The low-side diode, D1, serves no purpose unless some external force on  the motor acts in reverse direction  and shunts the output electrical power as a brake according to the mechanical input power.

This explanation made terms you have to look up.!!

Comment: Take a close look at how the 9 V battery is arranged, with (-) to ground and to the NPN collector. This is the correct arrangement for this weird set up. It will fly. I'll set up n LTSpice netlist for you, if that may help. It does work as shown. [Example schematic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mCBcB.png).

Comment: I see, but in this case, whether the transistor will work as switch or amplifier?

Comment: NOT AN AMPLIFIER but a low Vce(sat) unity  gain switch or linear unity gain N-PN junction . ..   A transistor  switch is an inverting amp with a Ice/Ib= 10 to 20 at Vce(sat.). But a reversed transistor  is an inverting switch has Ice/Ib=1 to .. slightly more in rare cases with near 0 Vce(sat) but high Rce so essentially useless here since you can invert the logic in software.  It has little or no value except in old days when super fast low Vce(sat) inversion could not be done as it is now with Enh-mode FETs. fuggetaboudit.

Comment: @jonk, I was not aware of improved Vce(sat) in this "reversed" configuration, and it answers a question I have from years ago, in my CRT repair days, when I found just such a "mistake" in a CGA/EGA monitor schematic. No internet to help back then, so thanks, I can let it go now.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why the designer would do that for a battery powered thing though. High stall current, reduced β and limited base drive current won't even allow the thing to saturate until after current has dropped so much that you don't care about Vce any more. This just seems like a design error to me. Or am I missing something? Also, is the absence of a resistor in the base related to this at all?

Comment: @SimonFitch I don't have a comprehensive view. Worse, I've never taken any courses in college. Just HS and then self-educated. I'm merely an ignorant hobbyist. My experiences say that you care about improved Vce saturation voltage differences only when those differences can make some important difference. (Meeting a LO logic level spec or improving the margin from 'almost good' to 'always good', for example.) Or when you are designing a circuit that uses the BJT in both modes (yes, that's even more often than the other case from what I've seen over the years.)

Comment: @SimonFitch I suspect there are other reasons related to the low-doping of the collector and the high base-collector reverse-voltage tolerance, as well, which can easily be 30 volts and often as much as 60 volts on common BJTs. (And much higher in less common ones.) It's been a long time since I wrote that here and I'm no longer sure where that base wire goes, sadly. Might come back to me. Just not now.

Comment: @SimonFitch it’s a mistake.  With reverse hFE =1 a 5 V logic current is not enough to drive a little DC motor